# How can I make inherits of postgresql by migration in laravel 5.2?

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I want yo make tables in postgresql with inherits, I foundes this http://packalyst.com/packages/package/thibaud-dauce/postgresql-schema form laravel 4.2, but it does not work whith laravel 5.2.

It shows me:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Fatal error: Class ThibaudDauce\PostgresqlSchema\PostgresqlSchemaServiceProvider' not found
```

when i try with composer update.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can pull in this package https://packagist.org/packages/rishi-ramawat/laravel-postgresql-inherit via composer like this for using it with Laravel **5.2.*** & **5.3.*** :

`composer require "rishi-ramawat/laravel-postgresql-inherit ~2.1.0"`

This is a package which I maintain and it currently supports Laravel **5.2.***, **5.3.*** & **5.4.***

For Laravel **5.4.*** you would have to do:

`composer require "rishi-ramawat/laravel-postgresql-inherit ~2.2"`

Please read the [**README**](https://github.com/rishi-ramawat/laravel-postgresql-inherit) of this package to find out more about the complete installation procedure.

Comment: Aren't you going to add support for laravel 6?

Answer (score 0):

You may run it:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE capitals INHERIT cities;");
```